# redirecting after POST in browser kills the POST request! why?

Tags: jquery, http, redirect, post

This brought me to the brink of madness.
I have a dynamic form,
which essentially is created via jquery
and then submitted via post:

```
//post_form
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

but I was calling this script like this:

```
post_form(url,params);
window.location = "/myurl";
```

putting the window.location after the post_form() call was never sending the post request, when, while debugging, I could see the code was executing...
Anybody care to give me a reason what was going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is executing, the form is being appended to the document body, and its submission starts, but at the instant you redirect away from the page, the page is disposed of along with your form, which aborts its ongoing submission. You have tagged your question with `jQuery` but you're not using any actual jQuery in your sample code — you should [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) your form and submit it using [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and only redirect after your success callback has been called by jQuery.

Comment: you are right, I was using jquery only to dynamically build the form, but there's no actual jquery in the code I submitted. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as if you're submitting a form, then very quickly click on a different link. The browser can only do one "main" request. Either it sends a POST request and refreshes the view with whatever it receives in response, or it sends a GET request and refreshes the view with whatever it receives in response. The script executes both in very quick succession, so the first POST request is canceled. Both actions are a "go to another page" action, they can't both happen at once.

Either do an AJAX POST request and redirect via Javascript when it's finished, or redirect via HTTP headers in response to the POST request.